# little o notation under integration

Tags: measure-theory, asymptotics, lp-spaces, ergodic-theory

I am reading a paper and it seems to be giving me more questions than answers. I will briefly explain the setup, as well as my attempts to make sense of them.

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is a probability space and $F:X\to X$ is a measure preserving transformation. Suppose that $p\geq 2$ and $h\in L^{p-1}(X)$. It is assumed that $\max_{0\leq k\leq n}|h\circ F^k|=o(n^{1/p})$ a.s.

However, does the previous statement not imply $h\in  L^p(X)$? Because certainly we have $|h|\leq \max_{0\leq k\leq n}|h\circ F^k|\leq n^{1/p}$ a.s for $n$ sufficiently large, and so on taking the $L^p$ norm, $\|h\|_p\leq n^{1/p}$. Or am I mistaken here?

Another question, which is related; Does $\max_{0\leq k\leq n}|h\circ F^k|=o(n^{1/p})$ a.s. imply that $\|\max_{0\leq k\leq n}|h\circ F^k|\|_p=o(n^{1/p})$? My guess is yes, because for any $C>0$, we can take $n$ sufficiently large so that

$\frac{\max_{0\leq k\leq n}|h\circ F^k|}{n^{1/p}}\leq C$. Applying the $L^p$-norm should give the result.

Does my logic appear to be flawed here? I am pretty new to big O/little O notation so any comments would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information that $\max_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}|h\circ F^k|=o\left(n^{1/p}\right)$ is equivalent to $$\tag{*}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1 {n^{1/p }} \max_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}\left|h\circ F^k\right|=0\mbox{ a.s.}.$$ The convergence $(*)$  holds automatically if $F$ is invariant, that is, if $h\circ F=h$ almost surely hence one can find a source of inspiration in nonergodic dynamical systems to find an example of function satisfying $(*)$ and which does not belong to $\mathbb L^p$. But it is true that $f\in\mathbb L^p$ implies (*), as a consequence of the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

The argument in the opening post uses the fact that $f/n$ is almost surely bounded, but the chosen $n$may depend on$\omega$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So there is no uniformity claimed of the constant. I still am not sure what you mean in the first paragraph. When you say 'it holds automatically if $F$ is invariant', are you referring to (*)? Moreover, I have not seen this definition of invariant before. Does this follow trivially from the more "standard" definition, $\mu(F^{-1}A)=\mu(A)$?

Comment: I just noticed the edit, I am assuming there is a limit infront of $(*)$

Comment: You are right. I do not understand what you mean by "Does this follow trivially from": how can a definition follow from something.

Comment: I should write characterisation instead of definition. i.e.,  is it true that invariance in the usual way ($\mu(F^{-1}A)=\mu(A)$ for all $A$measurable) implies what you wrote? (i.e. $h\circ F= h$ a.s. for all  $h$ measurable)